# Dar nombre al título de un Spinner

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

No consigo dar un nombre al texto por defecto del Spinner, se supone que es el prompt el que lo establece pero no funciona. Muestra Item 1 siempre, independientemente del prompt que introduzca.

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/formato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:prompt="@string/seleccionaFormato"
            android:entries="@array/Formato"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
```

```
<resources>
  
    <string name="seleccionaFormato">Selecciona formato</string>
    <string-array name="Formato">
        <item>DVD</item>
        <item>Blu-ray</item>
        <item>Online</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Tal vez debas usar [`android:spinnerMode="dialog"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30689722/13419694).